# Rendering style elements inside React components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to render the following line of code in React.

```
 <div className="img" style={{background-image: url(image.src)}}></div>
```

I'm getting a litany of parsing error. Would really appreciate some help in getting the correct React'ive' syntax on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-image` needs to be `backgroundImage` and then you need to do string interpolation on the url {{backgroundImage: `url(${image.src})`}}

otherwise when it is parsed how you have it now, react will think url is a function and attempt to call it with image.src.

this would also work

```
var image = "url(" + image.src + ")";
var style = {backgroundImage: image};
<div className="img" style={style}></div>
```